# ng-switch within ng-repeat, no errors, but not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set up a basic image gallery sort of thing whereby I can change currentImage to a certain number and the image with that number will be displayed.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="main_image" ng-switch on="current_image">
    <img ng-repeat="image in sorted_images" ng-src="{{ image.large }}" class="image {{ $index }}" ng-switch-when="{{ $index }}">
    <img ng-src="{{ sorted_images[0].medium }}" class="image 0" ng-switch-default >
</div>
```

Controller snippet (coffeescript):

```
main_image = el.find('.main_image');
main_image.on('click', ->
    scope.current_image = 1
```

It seems that while my controller is definitely updating the current_image variable, despite the change no switching occurs. Possibly this is because of $index? Not sure? Is it possible to use ng-switch within ng-repeat as i have done in the example above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have set `current_image` by using controller, and want to show respective image then you just need to use

```
<img src="{{ sorted_images[current_image].large }}" class="image {{ current_iamge }}" />
```

Comment: Much simpler solution, thanks! Just wondering though, do you know the reason why my other code did not work?

Comment: You are not required to use switch for that, you should have done it with ng-repeat and ng-show="current_image == $index".

Comment: If you use ng directives then you are not required to use {{ }}, you should do it by using $index. But I am not sure it is right way to do.